# how to access array[3..last] (ruby)

Tags: ruby, arrays

how can I access all array elements **from x** to the **last** one?

```
my_array= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
puts my_array[3..last]
```

Comment: @skaffman: I cannot see what you edited...it says tags but they are the same... :-)

Comment: there was a typo in your original 'ruby' tag.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

An index of -1 gives the last item in the array:

```
my_array[3..-1]
```

In fact, any negative index begins counting backwards from the end of the array.

Thanks to **Peter** for reminding me of the better way to do this.

Comment: It's quite late now, but for future Googlers: `arr.drop(x)`

Comment: I think correct format would be `my_array[-3..-1]`, `[3..-1]` will start counting from front.

Answer (score 10):

Use a negative index, as in `my_array[3..-1]`.

```
my_array= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
puts my_array[3..-1]
=> [4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
my_array= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
my_array[3..my_array.length-1] => [4, 5, 6]
```